# getting different random numbers in a loop not random

Tags: javascript

I am filling an array with random numbers with a loop, but the random number is exactly the same for each item in the array, I think this is because of the seed value that Math.rand() uses. How can i get a different number each time?

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    number[i] = getRandom(0, 100);
}

function getRandom(a, b){
    var num = Math.floor((Math.random()*b)+a);
    return num;
}
```

Comment: I get different numbers for all 10 entries when I take the code you posted here and run it in my Chrome console.

Comment: If you are simply returning the variable after assigning, directly return like this `return Math.floor((Math.random()*b)+a)`

Comment: `Math.random` is seeded by the current time - what environment are you running it in...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/VTtgA/1/)

```
var number = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    number[i] = getRandom(0, 100);
}

function getRandom(a, b) {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * b) + a);   
}
for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    alert(number[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/kzUUt/

You need to declare `number` though...

```
var number = new Array(10);
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    number[i] = getRandom(0, 100);
    console.log(number[i]);
}

function getRandom(a, b)
{
    var num = Math.floor((Math.random()*b)+a);
    return num;
}
```